# Route transaction messages to serverless instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless, google-cloud-run

In case of a high throughput transaction system, we route transactions to instances in an instance group based on some condition to ensure that the transactions are processed one after the other. For example, there might be a routing rule that says transactions has 'cancel' in the data might be routed to instance C while 'new' might be routed to instance A. This is relevant for some business logic.

However in the serverless world, we cannot name an instance because we don't know where it is running and how. How do we implement this kind of logic in such cases. Or does it goes against against the serverless paradigm.

Comment: Is the idea by @guillaumeblaquiere useful? Are you worried with the ordering of executions or with the naming of serverless containers run by cloud Run/functions?

Answer (score 1):

You can publish the event message in PubSub with an ordering key. like that, the message are delivered in order even if they aren't processed on the same instance.

Comment: 1. I am using PubSub with Cloud Functions and Cloud run. Pubsub subscriptions in cloud function triggers are created by default and hence do not give the option to add ordering key later on. Cloud run uses event arc and doesn't have this functionality. 2. Suppose if message A comes first and triggers a function and it triggers an instance 1, and message B comes a ms later and triggers instance 2. The instance 2 with message B could complete faster because it got the resources faster. Is there a better way to handle it?

Comment: You need to create a push subscription. You can't use Cloud Functions directly plugged on your Topic, you need an http functions, and a push subscription. Idem for EventArc, you use directly the topic and not a subscription with ordering key activated. Use raw things!